# Is the architectural model in the Clojure Pedestal framework an operational transform similar to Google Wave?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, google-wave, operational-transform, pedestal

Reading through the [Pedestal presentation](https://github.com/pedestal/samples/blob/master/slides/pedestal-intro-slides.pdf) (and reading [the sample source code](https://github.com/pedestal/samples/tree/master/chat)) - I see a model based on transforms and operations.

Is it true that Pedestal uses operational transformations (look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) and [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation)) similar to what was used in [Google Wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wave)?

Comment: Both use concepts and techniques that show up frequently in [Dataflow Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), [Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming), and [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). I think any links between pedastal and wave are related to the common design patterns between these various techniques for handling data between processes.

Comment: Great - add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both use concepts and techniques that show up frequently in [Dataflow Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), [Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming), and [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). Any links between Pedestal and Wave are related to the common design patterns between these various techniques for handling data between processes.